# finding the angle between two vectors

Tags: vectors

If $a,b$ and $c$ be three vectors such that $|\, a \,|=3$, $|\, b \,|=5$ and $|\, c \,|=7$ and $a+b+c=0$. Then find the angle between $a$ and $b$.

I tried by taking $a=-(b+c)$ and $b=-(c+a)$. But couldn't proceed further. Please help.

Comment: **mod** is not used for the modulus. You should use $\|\cdot \|$ or $|\cdot |$ instead. For the question itself, it is just a matter of applying the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines, as the condition is telling you that the three vectors form a triangle (this you need to understand)

Comment: Going off b00n h3T's comment: $|c|^2 = |a|^2 + |b|^2 - 2|a||b|cos(\theta)$. Solving for $\theta$ will give you the angle between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Sentient actually that will give you the "nose to tail" angle. The exterior angle (which is supplementary to that) corresponds to the angle between $a$ and $b$ from a common origin.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{a+b+c} &=\mathbf{0} \\
  \mathbf{c} &=-(\mathbf{a+b}) \\
  \mathbf{c}\cdot \mathbf{c} &= (\mathbf{a+b})\cdot (\mathbf{a+b}) \\
  c^2 &= a^2+b^2+2\mathbf{a\cdot b} \\
  2\mathbf{a\cdot b} &= c^2-a^2-b^2 \\
  \cos \theta_{ab} &= \frac{c^2-a^2-b^2}{2ab} \\
  &= \frac{7^2-3^2-5^2}{2(3)(5)} \\
  &= \frac{1}{2} \\
  \theta_{ab} &= 60^{\circ}
\end{align*}